# How to get "SQL Server Analysis Services Filter" to work?

Tags: filter, reporting-services

In an SharePoint 2013 BI Portal I am using two Report Services Report Web Parts with a common data source (.rsds file). Reports work fine and I want to filter the data of one report (or both reports if possible) without using the parameter pane but in a different Web Part instead. Therefore I added an SQL Server Analysis Services Filter Web Part in a different zone and tried to connect it to any data source but fail.

Under "Pick a data connection from:" I have the choices "A Web Part on this page" with the options "Status List Web Part" (list is empty) or "Office Data Connection file" (list is also empty). I can also choose "A SharePoint Data Connection" and specify an "Office Data Connection file", but when I choose the existing .rsds file, I get the message "Either the data connection URL does not resolve to a valid data connection or it resolves to a data connection of the wrong type. The data connection URL must be the valid URL of a data connection file on an SQL Server Analysis Services server."

Comment: Check this post and go through the steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2012/08/06/verifying-the-sharepoint-2013-configuration-for-accessing-workbooks-as-a-data-source-from-within-the-farm.aspx. Does everything work? Anything related errors/warnings found on CA's Health Analyzer? Just went through the configuring process of BI Portal successfully, but don't atm have time to assist you properly.

Comment: What I was able to get to work is the "Office Data Connection file" Option. I followed this advise to get it to go without Kerberos: http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/connecting-to-cubes-and-external-data-with-excel-in-sharepoint/ However, the filter works now but I cannot get it to connect to a report; an attempt to connect to ther Reporting Web Parts Fails because an empty "configure connection" dialogue pops up.

Comment: "SQL Server Analysis Services Filter" does not seem to be compatible with the "Report Services Report" Web Part. It does work with "Excel Web Access" Web Parts.

Comment: Is your SQL on version 2012 or 2014? If it's on 2012, make sure that the installation and all of its features are at least on the SP1 version (product version 11.00.3000.00 or later).

Comment: @moe: To make the filter and the Report Viewer compatible? SQL Server Version is 2012 (11.0.5...)